# How to pass in a String from Jenkins and convert to Int in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jenkins

a JS novice ~ simply looking to pass in a value from Jenkins into a pipeline script that is then converted to an Int.

**pipeline snippet**

```
 parameters {
        string(name: 'TIMES_TO_LOOP', defaultValue: ['1'], description: 'Number of times to loop')
```

**javascript snippet***

```
let timesToLoopThrough = 1; //set a default value

timesToLoopThrough = timesToLoopThrough.parseInt(agreementsToGenerate); //reset to value passed in

//use timesToLoopThrough in subsequent code
```

**error**

```
TypeError: timesToLoopThrough.parseInt is not a function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/convert-a-string-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 0):

You want to call parseInt on the class, not on the instance:

```
timesToLoopThrough = Number.parseInt(agreementsToGenerate);
```

or simply

```
timesToLoopThrough = parseInt(agreementsToGenerate);
```

if parseInt() is in global scope

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt)